# Adding Cordova/Phonegap plugins behind a proxy

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've successfully installed Cordova (clean install, under Windows), and I'm able to deploy a small app to Android, but unable to add any plugins behind my company's proxy. I've already tried setting every possible npm and git variable I could think of via:

```
npm config set proxy url:port
npm config set http-proxy url:port
npm config set https-proxy url:port
```

(replaced url:port with the actual proxy) and

```
git config --system --add http.proxy url:port
git config --global --add http.proxy url:port
```

but to no avail.

Every time I run something as simple as

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

I get the following:

```
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" via plugin registry
Error: Fetching plugin failed: Error: read ECONNRESET
at C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plugin.js:105:41
at _rejected  (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
at C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
at C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy way if you don't manage to make git work behind a proxy (sorry I won't be able to help you with that) is to

- download the git of the plugin using the zip download of git site
- extract the zip to some path
- run `cordova plugin add pathtotheextractedplugingit`

There are several ways to get the url of a plugin git repo, one of them is to go on [phonegap build plugin listing page](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) and then click on the plugin you need to get it's url.

For the splash screen plugin it would be https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Comment: I created a Plugin in my local drive and I still get proxy 407 error.

Answer (score 11):

The issue can be solved by setting HTTP_PROXY before you run the phonegap command:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport
```

Where your username:password is your login credentials. It's not using the setting in nodejs.

On unix you wouldn't use set.

Comment: THIS IS ALSO WORKING FOR ME. THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

This solution work form me in windows.
In your user folder:
C:\Users\your_user_name.gradle
If exists a file called
gradle.properties
Edit & add

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[Proxy_IP]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[your_username]
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=[your_password]
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[Proxy_IP]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[your_username]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=[your_password]
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

If the file does not exists, create it.
Replace the text between [] with your right data. Obviously, the [] must be deleted. I left the "proxyPort" with 8080 because is the default in the most of cases.

Comment: This worked for me using Linux too. I found gradle.properties in PROJECT_DIR/platforms/android/gradle.properties